# Degree 2 Veronese map

Tags: algebraic-geometry

On page 45 of Harris' *Algebraic Geometry: A First Course*, he states that the map $\mathbb{P}^2\to \mathbb{P}^5$ defined by $$[a,b,c]\mapsto [a^2,b^2,c^2,2ab,2ac,2bc]$$ is the degree 2 Veronese map. I thought the degree 2 Veronese map was defined as $$[a,b,c]\mapsto [a^2,b^2,c^2,ab,ac,bc].$$ Why are these two maps the same?

Comment: Because $[X_0 : X_1 : X_2 : X_3 : X_4 : X_5] \mapsto [X_0 : X_1 : X_2 : \frac 1 2 X_3 : \frac 1 2 X_4 : \frac 1 2 X_5]$ is an isomorphism of $\mathbb P^5$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Projective planes are said to bee isomorphic if they can be related by an element of $PGL(\mathbb C)$ (the projective linear group.)

One can make this explicit by checking that isomorphisms $\mathbb C^6 \to \mathbb C^6$ decend to isomorphisms of $\mathbb P^5$  by simply taking a quotient by $K^{\times}$.

Your isomorphism is nothing but the $\mathbb C$-linear map $(x_0,\dots x_5) \mapsto (x_0,x_1,x_2,\frac{1}{2}x_3,\frac{1}{2}x_4,\frac{1}{2}x_5)$ which factors through the usual identification by scalars to an isomorphism of $\mathbb P^5$. Because this is an isomorphism of projective spaces, both are Veronese maps.